# error message when trying to import a package

Tags: python, import, package

I try to import a package called "processing" that is delivered with the QGIS Application. It is no problem to import that package in the Python console inside QGIS. I also managed to locate it:

```
>>>import processing
>>>processing.__file__
'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing\\__init__.py'
```

But my goal is to import that package in a standalone Python script that runs **outside** the QGIS App. I've found an example for that, and according to the example I tried (code abstract only):

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Program files\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\processing')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import Processing
```

The subdirectory `\processing\core` is present, and the `Processing.py` file in that dir as well. Everything seems ok.

`print sys.path` gives me (along with many others):

```
['C:\\Program files\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\processing']
```

But when I run my script I get an error message telling me:

> ImportError: No module named processing.core.Processing

Why can that package or module not be found? Maybe an error in the calling syntax or the path?

Comment: Python scans the `sys.path` directories for modules, so you want to add the parent of the package... `'C:\\Program files\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gone one directory too deep. `from processing.core.Processing import Processing` will cause python to look for something called "processing" in the `sys.path` directories, that is, `"'C:\\Program files\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\processing\\processing"`.

Instead do

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Program files\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
```

Note that this will make all modules in `plugins` visible.

Comment: Great, it works. But now I get new error messages: like Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python\qgis\utils.py", line 171, i
n qgis_excepthook     sorry, the edit box tells me that my coment is too long. Don't know how to provide the complete Error message? It seems like the module or package is found now, but new problems came up.

Comment: Generally asking: are there differences I have to consider when importing something **inside** an application versus **outside** ??

Comment: That could mean that there are more directories in "QGIS Essen" that need to be added to `sys.path`.

Comment: You could post the traceback as an update to your question. But you are in the whack-a-mole portion of your project. If it looks like an import issue, find the missing module. Its possible that this app is using a different python interpreter or even an embedded interpreter and that what you want to do isn't possible. But likely its just a question of patchign a few holes.

Answer (score 0):

You might try posting this question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Yep, you need all the paths. To help your "whack a mole phase" along try starting here: 
http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#run-python-code-when-qgis-starts

They are setting paths in the OS -vs- setting them in Python. Should be the same though.

FWIW I tried working through path additions and ended up looking for imports of QgsFeature and QgsGeometry that show up in "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python\qgis__init__.py" line 36. These did not pop up in a search by file name or contents so I could not find the next path to add ... maybe another module has to be installed?

My process is to get the error, then search for the object that could not be imported in file names & contents. Once you find the file, you have the directory and thus path. Just keep chipping away at it.

In case it helps, here's what I added for paths so far:

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python')
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\python27\\lib\\site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\qgis\\core')
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\python\\qgis\\gui')
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGIS Essen\\apps\\qgis\\bin')
```

Sorry I could not be of more assistance.

Comment: Hello all, believe it or not, today (after restart of PC), it works fine. Maybe I did too much testing resulting in path constructions that confused not only myself but even the PC. So one fat mole is catched now! Thanks a lot!